# Subtract Values based on Multiple Grouping Factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, dplyr, subtraction

I have a dataset with phosphorus concentrations for 17 separate days (concentrations are cumulative, so increase from Day1 to Day102 in all cases). There are 22 different treatments (column = Trmt). Each Trmt has 3 Levels (Level = X, Y, Z). 2 measurements per Level for a total of 6 per Trmt.

My goal is to plot a 3-line graph of Days (x-axis; numeric) by Concentration (y-axis) using ggplot2. Data should be grouped by Trmt, Level and day for a total of 51 measurements (3 lines x 17 days).

My data looks as follows:

```
structure(list(Trmt = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), .Label = c("A01nF", "A01yT", "A02nF", "A02yT", "A03nF", "A03yT", "A04nF", "A04yT", "A05nF", "A05yT", "A06nF", "A06yT", "A07nF", "A07yT", "A08nF", "A08yT", "A10nF", "A10yT", "A11nF", "A11yT", "A13nF", "A13yT"), class = "factor"), Level = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), Day1 = c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L), Day2 = c(10L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 7L), Day4 = c(11L, 12L, 14L, 11L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 15L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 15L, 15L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 11L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 14L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 15L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 14L), Day7 = c(19L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 17L, 20L, 16L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 19L, 17L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 17L, 20L, 19L, 20L, 19L, 20L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 19L, 20L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 18L, 20L, 17L, 19L, 17L, 19L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 16L, 19L, 16L, 17L, 16L, 20L, 16L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 20L, 17L, 19L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 18L, 16L, 17L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 16L, 20L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 16L, 20L), Day10 = c(24L, 23L, 23L, 21L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 25L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 22L, 25L, 24L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 22L, 25L, 25L, 22L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 23L, 25L, 23L, 21L, 23L, 22L, 24L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 22L, 25L, 23L, 23L, 21L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 22L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 24L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 21L, 25L, 25L, 22L, 21L, 25L, 24L, 22L, 21L, 25L, 24L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 24L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 23L, 25L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 25L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 21L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 23L, 22L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 21L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 21L), Day13 = c(29L, 29L, 26L, 27L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 26L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 27L, 26L, 29L, 28L, 26L, 30L, 28L, 29L, 27L, 28L, 26L, 29L, 28L, 30L, 26L, 27L, 30L, 26L, 29L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 28L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 29L, 27L, 29L, 27L, 30L, 26L, 27L, 30L, 26L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 29L, 26L, 29L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 28L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 28L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 28L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 27L, 30L, 27L, 30L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 27L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 26L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 27L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 26L, 30L, 28L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 26L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 29L, 26L, 29L, 26L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 26L, 27L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 27L, 30L, 28L, 26L, 30L, 27L, 30L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 26L), Day18 = c(32L, 31L, 32L, 31L, 31L, 34L, 32L, 34L, 32L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 35L, 34L, 34L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 32L, 35L, 31L, 31L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 31L, 32L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 31L, 35L, 35L, 31L, 34L, 32L, 32L, 34L, 33L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 35L, 31L, 35L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 34L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 34L, 31L, 34L, 33L, 35L, 35L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 34L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 32L, 35L, 32L, 32L, 35L, 33L, 34L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 32L, 32L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 32L, 34L, 34L, 31L, 35L, 31L, 35L), Day23 = c(39L, 40L, 38L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 37L, 36L, 37L, 36L, 36L, 38L, 40L, 38L, 37L, 36L, 36L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 40L, 36L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 37L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 37L, 40L, 36L, 38L, 37L, 40L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 40L, 38L, 37L, 36L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 39L, 40L, 39L, 37L, 39L, 39L, 37L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 39L, 37L, 36L, 37L, 40L, 36L, 39L, 40L, 39L, 40L, 39L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 37L, 40L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 40L, 40L, 36L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 37L, 37L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 37L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 38L, 36L, 37L, 36L, 36L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 36L, 39L, 38L, 40L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 36L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 38L, 37L, 38L), Day28 = c(42L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 42L, 45L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 42L, 44L, 42L, 44L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 44L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 43L, 42L, 43L, 42L, 41L, 44L, 43L, 43L, 42L, 42L, 44L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 45L, 44L, 45L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 41L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 42L, 45L, 41L, 42L, 45L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 44L, 42L, 41L, 43L, 41L, 44L, 43L, 41L, 45L, 42L, 45L, 41L, 45L, 41L, 45L, 42L, 45L, 42L, 45L, 45L, 41L, 41L, 43L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 41L, 42L, 44L, 43L, 45L, 41L, 41L, 44L, 41L, 44L, 43L, 43L, 45L, 44L, 41L, 44L, 43L, 42L, 45L, 45L, 41L, 45L, 42L, 41L, 44L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 43L, 41L, 41L, 45L, 41L, 42L, 45L, 41L, 44L), Day35 = c(50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 48L, 46L, 50L, 46L, 48L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 46L, 49L, 46L, 47L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 49L, 46L, 47L, 49L, 46L, 49L, 50L, 49L, 46L, 49L, 50L, 46L, 48L, 50L, 46L, 50L, 48L, 46L, 48L, 50L, 50L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 49L, 48L, 46L, 46L, 48L, 50L, 46L, 49L, 48L, 46L, 49L, 50L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 50L, 49L, 47L, 48L, 50L, 50L, 46L, 47L, 46L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 47L, 49L, 48L, 49L, 46L, 47L, 50L, 47L, 50L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 47L, 46L, 50L, 46L, 50L, 50L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 46L, 47L, 50L, 47L, 48L, 46L, 50L, 49L, 46L, 46L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 46L, 49L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 50L, 47L, 46L, 48L, 50L, 48L, 46L, 46L), Day42 = c(52L, 51L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 54L, 52L, 51L, 55L, 51L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 55L, 54L, 55L, 51L, 51L, 55L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 55L, 53L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 51L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 51L, 51L, 54L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 55L, 54L, 54L, 52L, 52L, 55L, 55L, 51L, 55L, 52L, 55L, 51L, 53L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 51L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 52L, 54L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 52L, 55L, 52L, 54L, 51L, 52L, 55L, 51L, 52L, 55L, 54L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 55L, 51L, 51L, 55L, 52L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 53L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 51L, 54L, 54L, 51L, 53L, 55L, 51L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 52L, 52L, 54L, 51L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 55L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 53L, 54L, 51L, 51L, 54L, 55L, 52L), Day52 = c(59L, 57L, 56L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 57L, 59L, 57L, 56L, 58L, 58L, 60L, 59L, 56L, 56L, 60L, 57L, 60L, 57L, 59L, 56L, 60L, 59L, 59L, 56L, 60L, 58L, 60L, 57L, 57L, 60L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 56L, 58L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 56L, 58L, 56L, 57L, 60L, 58L, 59L, 58L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 60L, 59L, 60L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 57L, 60L, 59L, 57L, 60L, 56L, 57L, 56L, 58L, 60L, 56L, 58L, 56L, 60L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 60L, 58L, 59L, 58L, 60L, 59L, 58L, 56L, 56L, 58L, 57L, 60L, 56L, 58L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 60L, 59L, 60L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 57L, 57L, 60L, 59L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 57L, 59L, 58L, 60L, 59L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 56L, 57L, 60L, 58L, 57L, 56L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 56L, 58L, 60L), Day62 = c(67L, 65L, 68L, 65L, 69L, 70L, 69L, 66L, 65L, 70L, 70L, 65L, 67L, 68L, 65L, 67L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 68L, 68L, 66L, 65L, 67L, 66L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 68L, 67L, 66L, 69L, 65L, 65L, 69L, 66L, 69L, 68L, 69L, 67L, 65L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 67L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 69L, 68L, 66L, 67L, 66L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 67L, 66L, 65L, 69L, 67L, 66L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 70L, 67L, 69L, 66L, 67L, 65L, 70L, 65L, 70L, 66L, 66L, 69L, 68L, 65L, 65L, 67L, 68L, 67L, 69L, 68L, 69L, 66L, 68L, 70L, 69L, 68L, 70L, 66L, 69L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 65L, 69L, 69L, 67L, 70L, 65L, 70L, 69L, 66L, 68L, 67L, 68L, 66L, 65L, 67L, 70L, 66L, 67L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 70L), Day72 = c(74L, 74L, 71L, 75L, 74L, 71L, 75L, 71L, 75L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 75L, 73L, 75L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 71L, 74L, 72L, 71L, 71L, 74L, 74L, 73L, 72L, 73L, 71L, 71L, 75L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 73L, 71L, 71L, 74L, 71L, 73L, 75L, 75L, 74L, 71L, 75L, 74L, 72L, 72L, 71L, 72L, 75L, 73L, 74L, 71L, 75L, 75L, 73L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 72L, 75L, 72L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 72L, 72L, 74L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 75L, 74L, 75L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 72L, 75L, 73L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 72L, 75L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 73L, 72L, 71L, 75L, 75L, 74L, 73L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 71L, 71L, 74L, 72L, 73L, 71L, 75L, 74L, 75L, 74L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 72L, 75L, 73L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 75L, 75L, 72L, 73L, 75L, 75L), Day82 = c(76L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 77L, 78L, 77L, 80L, 79L, 80L, 76L, 76L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 80L, 78L, 76L, 79L, 76L, 77L, 76L, 79L, 78L, 76L, 76L, 79L, 79L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 80L, 77L, 77L, 76L, 77L, 79L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 80L, 79L, 76L, 79L, 77L, 76L, 80L, 78L, 77L, 79L, 80L, 77L, 80L, 78L, 79L, 78L, 76L, 76L, 79L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 80L, 79L, 78L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 77L, 77L, 80L, 77L, 80L, 77L, 76L, 77L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 80L, 79L, 77L, 78L, 80L, 80L, 79L, 80L, 79L, 79L, 78L, 76L, 76L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 79L, 78L, 76L, 79L, 77L, 77L, 76L, 76L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 78L, 76L, 78L, 79L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 76L, 79L, 78L, 77L), Day92 = c(85L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 83L, 82L, 83L, 82L, 85L, 85L, 82L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 81L, 81L, 84L, 81L, 85L, 82L, 85L, 84L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 82L, 84L, 84L, 81L, 85L, 83L, 85L, 82L, 81L, 83L, 83L, 85L, 83L, 81L, 83L, 82L, 84L, 83L, 83L, 82L, 85L, 85L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 85L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 84L, 81L, 85L, 81L, 82L, 81L, 81L, 85L, 83L, 81L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 83L, 85L, 85L, 83L, 81L, 85L, 81L, 84L, 83L, 83L, 85L, 83L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 82L, 83L, 81L, 84L, 83L, 84L, 82L, 83L, 81L, 83L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 85L, 85L, 84L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 84L, 81L, 84L, 81L, 81L, 84L, 84L, 83L, 83L, 82L, 82L, 81L, 85L, 85L, 82L, 83L, 81L, 83L, 82L, 84L, 83L, 82L, 84L, 81L, 83L, 82L, 84L, 85L), Day102 = c(89L, 88L, 88L, 90L, 88L, 90L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 87L, 90L, 86L, 86L, 89L, 86L, 89L, 90L, 88L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 87L, 90L, 86L, 90L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 88L, 90L, 88L, 87L, 89L, 90L, 88L, 87L, 89L, 88L, 87L, 86L, 90L, 86L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 88L, 90L, 86L, 88L, 88L, 90L, 89L, 88L, 88L, 90L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 87L, 90L, 89L, 87L, 90L, 90L, 86L, 87L, 86L, 90L, 88L, 87L, 86L, 88L, 90L, 86L, 89L, 90L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 86L, 86L, 89L, 89L, 86L, 87L, 86L, 86L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 88L, 86L, 88L, 88L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 89L, 89L, 86L, 90L, 89L, 89L, 88L, 90L, 88L, 86L, 90L, 90L, 87L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 88L, 90L, 90L, 87L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 89L, 86L, 88L, 89L, 88L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -132L))
```

Required libraries:
tidyr, plyr, ggplot2

The steps that I have taken so far are to:

Convert the data to long format (df = name of dataset):

```
    Fig1 <- gather(df, day, phosphorus, Day1:Day102, factor_key=TRUE)
```

Change the factor day to numeric

```
    df$day2 <-revalue(df$day, c("Day1"="1", "Day2"="2", "Day4"="4", "Day7"="7", "Day10"="10", "Day13"="13", "Day18"="18", "Day23" = "23","Day28" = "28", "Day35" = "35", "Day42" = "42", "Day52" = "52", "Day62" = "62", "Day72" = "72", "Day82" = "82", Day92" = "92", "Day102" = "102"))
```

and

```
df$day3 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$day2))
```

Group by Trmt, Level and day3

```
 GroupedDF <- df %>% group_by(Trmt, Level, day3)
 GroupedCO2M <- GroupedDF %>% summarise(disp = mean(phosphorus))
```

I would now like to subtract values by accounting for Trmt and Level, thus reducing the number of rows from 102 to 51. I would like to subtract 'yT' Trmt cases from respective 'nF' cases, uniquely for each Level (X, Y and Z). For example, subtract A01yT_X from A01nf_X, A01yT_Y from A01nf_Y, A01yT_Z from A01nf_Z etc. This should give a total of 51 points, 17 for each Level.

Here is a figure of what I have in mind:

[image]

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you check your `dput`? It seems incomplete.

Comment: Thanks. Is that working now?

Comment: Hi tabtimm, I am almost done with solving your problem. So the plot you have, is it only for 1 treatment like A01?

Comment: Because you mentioned subtracting, A01yT_X from A01nf_X, so I am thinking it goes onto to  A02yT_X .. And you will have treatments A01.. A92 right?

Comment: There are 22 treatments, 11 end on 'yT' and 11 on 'nf'. There are 3 levels called X, Y & Z. So, there are basically 'pairs', like A01nf_X and A01yT_X,  A01nf_Y and A01yT_Y, A01nf_Z and A01yT_Z,  A02nf_X and A02yT_X,  etc. I would like to subtract 'yT' treatments from 'nf' treatments, conditional that the other grouping factors like levels (X, Y & Z) as well as site (A01, A02 etc) are preserved. I had concatenated grouping factors earlier. As such, A01yT_X should only be subtracted from A01nf_X  because they both share the 'X' level and the 'A01' site. I hope that makes sense? Many thanks!

Comment: Ok yes I did that correctly. However the plot you showed, it has 3 lines (X,Y,Z) and 18 days. Is this for 1 site, e.g 'A01' or average across all sites?

Comment: I think the visualized plot has 17 days? Or do you mean the plot derived from the data that I provide? As you say, there will be three lines for each level (i.e. X,Y,Z). The lines are based on averages across all sites, conditional of the same treatment (i.e. 'nf' vs 'yT') and level (X,Y,Z). Once averaged across sites of the same treatment, 'yT' treatments should subtracted from 'nf' treatments, to generate a single value per level  (X,Y,Z) and day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for sharing the data. The data you have posted is a bit long, hence might not be able to totally copy and paste

Your data is in the wide format, and you need to find the average for each measurement between similar groups (defined by Day, Level, Treatment). So we can work on this in the wide format:

```
tmp <- Data %>% group_by(Trmt,Level) %>% summarise_all(mean)
    > head(tmp)
# A tibble: 6 x 19
# Groups:   Trmt [2]
  Trmt  Level  Day1  Day2  Day4  Day7 Day10 Day13 Day18 Day23 Day28 Day35 Day42
  <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A01nF X       3.5   8    12    19    23    29.5  32.5  36.5  42      50  53  
2 A01nF Y       4.5   9.5  13    17.5  21    28    32.5  36    43.5    48  54.5
3 A01nF Z       1     8.5  13.5  18.5  22.5  28.5  33    37.5  43      49  51.5
4 A01yT X       2.5   8.5  11    19.5  22.5  28    31.5  38    43      50  52.5
5 A01yT Y       2.5   7.5  13.5  17    22    29.5  31    38.5  43.5    49  52.5
6 A01yT Z       3     7    14.5  18    23    28    33    38    43.5    48  54
```

This gives you the average for each Trmt,Level, and each column (Day) is average separately. Next step is to define the 2 subgroups under Trmt (nF and yT for A01,A02..), and for this we can introduce a subgroup called "site", which is Trmt without the nF,yT. Once you group your data.frame with this "site" and level, the first row will always be nF, and 2nd row yT, so taking the diff for all your Day columns within this grouping, will give you the difference. So we do it like this:

```
    # need to ungroup Trmt to remove it later
    tmp <- tmp%>% ungroup(Trmt) %>% 
    mutate(site = sub("[yn][TF]","",Trmt)) %>% 
    select(-Trmt) %>% 
    group_by(site,Level) %>% 
    summarize_all(diff)
```

Now you have the nF - yT values for each treatment, each level and each day

```
> head(tmp)
# A tibble: 6 x 19
# Groups:   site [2]
  site  Level  Day1  Day2  Day4  Day7 Day10 Day13 Day18 Day23 Day28 Day35 Day42
  <chr> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A01   X      -1     0.5  -1     0.5  -0.5  -1.5  -1     1.5   1     0    -0.5
2 A01   Y      -2    -2     0.5  -0.5   1     1.5  -1.5   2.5   0     1    -2  
3 A01   Z       2    -1.5   1    -0.5   0.5  -0.5   0     0.5   0.5  -1     2.5
4 A02   X       1.5   1     1.5   1    -1    -1.5   2    -1.5  -1.5  -1     2  
5 A02   Y       0.5   0    -1.5  -1     0.5   1.5  -0.5  -3    -1.5   0     1  
6 A02   Z       4     2     1     0.5   1.5   0     2.5   0.5   0.5   1.5   0
```

Come the last part, which is to plot. We convert it to long and also make "Day", a numeric form of day.

```
plotdf <- gather(tmp, day, Diff, Day1:Day102, factor_key=TRUE) %>%
mutate(Day=as.numeric(sub("Day","",day)))
# and plot

ggplot(plotdf,aes(x=Day,y=Diff,col=Level,shape=Level)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~site) + scale_color_manual(values=c("grey10","grey40","grey80"))
```

[image]

Plot above shows the difference for each site. For diff that is the average across all sites:

```
meandf <- plotdf %>% group_by(Level,Day) %>% summarize(Diff=mean(Diff))
ggplot(meandf,aes(x=Day,y=Diff,col=Level,shape=Level)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values=c("grey10","grey40","grey80"))
```

[image]
example dataset, subsetted for Day1, Day2 and Day4

```
Data <- structure(list(Trmt = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L
), .Label = c("A01nF", "A01yT", "A02nF", "A02yT", "A03nF", "A03yT", 
"A04nF", "A04yT", "A05nF", "A05yT", "A06nF", "A06yT", "A07nF", 
"A07yT", "A08nF", "A08yT", "A10nF", "A10yT", "A11nF", "A11yT", 
"A13nF", "A13yT"), class = "factor"), Level = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), Day1 = c(3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 4L), Day2 = c(10L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 
6L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
9L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 
10L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 
10L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 
10L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 
9L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 
9L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 
8L, 8L, 7L), Day4 = c(11L, 12L, 14L, 11L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 
15L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 15L, 15L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 
11L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 11L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 14L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 
11L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 
15L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 
15L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 
11L, 15L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 
15L, 14L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 
11L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-132L))
```